# Shopify Buy Button Error: "cannot read property '1' of null"

Tags: shopify

When I'm creating a Shopify "Buy Button" of any type, the generated HTML code does not work. The Chrome Developer Tools Console tells me: `buy-button-storefront.js:2999`: `cannot read property '1' of null`.

In the Chrome debugger, I see that the function `formatMoney(amount, format)` is called with a `format` parameter which does not work with the `placeholderRegex`:

[image: Chrome debugger]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

When `money_format` isn't set correctly, Shopify's formatMoney() regex fails.

Check your money format:
`console.log(Shopify.api.getMoneyFormat())`

For me, this was returning `$` instead of `${{amount}}` - It looks like yours is returning `€` instead of `€{{amount}}`

After checking my script, I *was* setting the format correctly to begin with - but my JS file had a .liquid extension - so Shopify was seeing {{amount}} as a variable, which rendered blank on the client side. You can avoid this behaviour by using the `%raw%` tags in your liquid file.

`{% raw %}
  var money_format = '${{amount}}';
{% endraw %}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript SDk to avoid this problem . Generate a new snippet from Buy Button > JavaScript SDk > Generate code .

I think then it will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

I seen this problem a handful of times, its odd it just seems to pop up and I've never actually got to the bottom of it.

Sometimes resetting the money format does the trick

```
<script>Shopify.money_format = "{{ shop.money_format }}";</script>
```

I can't take credit for that,I found it on github a while back

Comment: I've just had this issue again, I included {{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }} and this seemed to resolve the error.